# Как в лейбле отображать десятичные числа в виде 001, а не 1?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в лейбле (label1) отображать десятичные числа в виде 001, а не 1 ? И отображать десятичные числа в виде 012, а не 12. При этом десятичное значение берется из listBox3.SelectedIndex.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: `myInt.ToString("D3");`

Comment: Лабел отображает ТОЛЬКО строковый тип. Преобразование числа производится по умолчанию, при котором zero-padding не предусмотрен в принципе. Преобразуйте число в строку с ведущими нулями явно.

Comment: Интересует в WinForms. Если можно объясните детальнее с примерами как для новичка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы определить способ форматирования числовых данных, можно создать строку настраиваемого числового формата, состоящую из одного или нескольких описателей настраиваемого формата. Строка настраиваемого числового формата — это любая строка формата, не являющаяся строкой стандартного числового формата.

*Знак-заместитель нуля* - 
Заменяет ноль соответствующей цифрой, если такая имеется. В противном случае в результирующей строке будет стоять ноль.

```
double value;

 value = 123;
 Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00000"));
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00000}", value));
 // Displays 00123
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, помогли все три варианта.

```
label1.Text = listBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString("D3"); // 1-ый вариант
label1.Text = listBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString("000"); // 2-ой вариант
label1.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", listBox3.SelectedIndex); // 3-ий вариант
```

Comment: Еще один вариант для C#6.0 и выше: `label1.Text = $"{listBox3.SelectedIndex:000}";`